# How to publish Angular2 components on NPM and can i use athe Angular CLI to do the work?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular2-components

I would like to create and share an Angular 2 component on NPM and Github. Can I use the Angular CLI to do it? Are there steps to follow in coding the apps in order to match component publishing criteria?

Comment: Same here... It's too  hard finding an apt guide for it .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the better solution which worked fine for me. Have a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library), using yoman we can create our angular2 components as npm package. Enjoy !!

Comment: Does this work with templateUrl, styleUrls and images?